# Use of filter and drop shadow

Tags: html, css

The following code will be used for educational purposes. It is to simply demonstrate how to apply a drop-shadow using a CSS3 filter. Any feedback on areas where I have not used best practices would be great.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/sibizudo/1)

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop Shadow</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="drop-shadow.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Introduction to the text shadow property -->
    <div class="container one">
       <img width="250" height="250" src="http://iancottam.co.uk/img/footy.png">
    </div>
    <div class="container two">
       <img width="250" height="250" src="http://iancottam.co.uk/img/footy.png">
    </div>
    <!-- Support Info: http://caniuse.com/css-filters -->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
    body{
            background: #ccc;
            margin: 0;
    }
    h1{
        font-size: 5em;
        font-family: Georgia;
    }
    .container{
        padding: 20px 50px;
    }
    .one img{
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px black);
    }
    .two{
        background: black;
    }
    .two img{
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-15px 0px 20px white);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code it's perfectly fine

I would just change, to stress the fact that the images are the same:

```
.container img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    content: url("http://iancottam.co.uk/img/footy.png");
}
```

and then

```
<div class="container one">
   <img>
</div>
<div class="container two">
   <img>
</div>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sibizudo/2/)

Comment: CSS backgrounds aren't semantically the same as `<img>` tags. For example, some browsers will ignore CSS backgrounds when printing.

Comment: @200_success:  It's true that CSS backgrounds aren't the same than img; but I am not using CSS backgrounds.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected. I had read it carelessly since I wasn't familiar with this [feature of CSS 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11173991/1157100).

Comment: Never mind :-)  !!

Comment: There's no real benefit to this suggestion, it's just change for the sake of change.

Comment: @cimmanon I mostly agree with you, there isn't much benefit in my answer. I admited that already ! It's only, for demonstration purposes, to make clearer that the images are the same, and that the difference comes from the filter.